# how To Use Change event of BootstrapSlider in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

i Have Two Question About Bootstarp Slider 
First How can I use change event in BootstrapSlider and get value 
and Second is how to change initial value of bootstrap slider

Comment: what have you done so far? and what library you are using ?

Comment: bootstrap-slider framework https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider

Comment: no it is not my answer

Comment: i have updated my pen https://codepen.io/nijeesh4all/pen/yLyggza?editors=1111

Comment: add can you add pen for refresh initial value

Comment: i have set the initial value as 20. you can set the inital value by setting attribute `data-slider-value=<value>`

Comment: i want initial run time and can change value with parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can use   `.on('chnage', callback_function)` to listen to value changes

and set the `data-slider-value=< any number >` to initialize the starting value

```
 <input
        type="text"
        name="somename"
        data-slider-value="20"
        data-provide="slider"
        data-slider-min="1"
        data-slider-max="100"
        data-slider-step="1"
        data-slider-tooltip="hide"
    >

    // Instantiate a slider
    var mySlider = $("input").slider();

    //This will get called for every chnage
    mySlider.on('change',function(){
      //getting value from slider
     var value = mySlider.slider('getValue');
      console.log(value)
    })
```